# React button to open SharePoint Document Picker

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, react, office-ui-fabric-react

I have seen and experimented with the Property Pane controls that allow you to select a document or image from a pane and was curious if anyone has seen this same capability available from a button click inside of a SPFx Web Part Form.

I have looked around for something that will just return the URL to a value after selection but have not found anything like it.

I do not want the Property Pane to hold the value or the button, it would be on the SPFx Web Part component itself.

Example (When button is clicked to select image):

[React Comparer](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-comparer)